# What is the cleanest valid TypeScript equivalent of the three dots syntax?

Tags: javascript, typescript, syntax

I am trying to filter out `props` in my TypeScript/React code, however rest/spread properties (three dot syntax `...`) are [not supported in TypeScript yet](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10727):

```
const NavItemPass = (props) => {
    const { active, activeKey, activeHref, ...rest } = props;
    return <NavItem {...rest} />;
};
```

What would be the cleanest immutable equivalent syntax with TypeScript 1.8?

Comment: I am trying `const props2 = Object.assign({}, props);` followed by `delete props2.active`, etc. but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please use the correct name for the three dots, which is "rest/spread properties".

Comment: Thanks for the formal name, good to have it at hand when searching for information. I have updated the question, but left the title as is, so that people can find it with either denomination.

Answer (score 2):

Babel does it by creating a function that creates a new object. You may want to do that, making a nice reusable one, and then use that.

I'll give an example in JavaScript, which you can readily translate to TypeScript:

```
function objectWithout(obj, keys) {
    let target = {};
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
        if (keys.indexOf(k) == -1) {
            target[k] = obj[k];
        }
    });
    return target;
}
```

Then

```
const NavItemPass = (props) => {
    return React.createElement(NavItem, objectWithout(props, ["active", "activeKey", "activeHref"]));
};
```

Not very satisfying. :-|

Comment: @ErwinMayer: :-) Hopefully TypeScript will get spread and rest soon. They're amazingly helpful. I'm actively hoping someone else has a better solution than the above, though, in the meantime.